# How to display data from json url using php decode?

Tags: php, json, api

I am not able to display data from this url using php json decode:
https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Hello%20World!&langpair=en|it

here is the data provider:
https://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php

thanks.

What I want is to setup a form to submit words and get translation back from their API.

here is my code sample:

```html
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Hello%20World!&langpair=en|it');

// parse the JSON
$data = json_decode($json);

// show the translation
echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: Where's your code, how do you access this url/data?

Comment: `$data` will be an object/array after `json_decode`, have you tried to `var_dump($data)` and select the field/data you really want?

Comment: I don't know how to do that! :/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you might likely want to write some for loops with `if` statements to display your data as you wish:

---

#### Test

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Hello%20World!&langpair=en|it');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

if (isset($data["responseData"])) {

    foreach ($data["responseData"] as $key => $value) {
        // This if is to only display the translatedText value //
        if ($key == 'translatedText' && !is_null($value)) {
            $html = $value;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Something is not right!";
}

echo $html;
```

#### Output

```
Ciao Mondo!
```

---

```
<?php

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>read JSON from URL</title>
</head>
<body>
';

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Hello%20World!&langpair=en|it');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data["responseData"] as $key => $value) {
    // This if is to only display the translatedText value //
    if ($key == 'translatedText' && !is_null($value)) {
        $html .= '<p>' . $value . '</p>';
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

$html .= '
</body>
</html>';

echo $html;

?>
```

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>read JSON from URL</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Ciao Mondo!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice, but this is non formatted data, I want only to display translatedText.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code but did not work! can you clean it from html, I need to try just the php code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After many researches I got it working this way:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=Map&langpair=en|it');  
$obj = json_decode($json);   
echo $obj->responseData->translatedText;
```

thank you all.